# Getting L_ERRORCODE0=10001& Timeout processing request

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am trying to simulate a dummy parallel payment to 2 users using curl.
I have done everything as per documentation but the problem is I am getting

> Getting L_ERRORCODE0=10001& Timeout processing request

I dont know why.

My code is as follows:

```
<?php
   $data = array(
     'USER'=>urlencode('xxx'),
     'PWD'=>urlencode('xxxx'),
     'SIGNATURE'=>urlencode('xxxx'),
     'VERSION'=>urlencode('86.0'),
     'METHOD'=>urlencode('SetExpressCheckout'),
     'RETURNURL'=>urlencode('http://75.125.190.162:7132/sample/php_nvp_samples/myCheckout.php'),
     'CANCELURL'=>urlencode('http://75.125.190.162:7132/sample/php_nvp_samples/myCheckout.php'),
     'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE'=>urlencode('USD'),
     'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT'=>urlencode('300'),
     'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT'=>urlencode('200'),
     'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT'=>urlencode('100'),
     'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC'=>urlencode('Summer Vacation trip'),
     'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID'=>urlencode('himans_1331094418_biz@smartdatainc.net'),
     'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION'=>urlencode('Order'),
     'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTREQUESTID'=>urlencode('CART26488-PAYMENT0'),
     'PAYMENTREQUEST_1_CURRENCYCODE'=>urlencode('USD'),
     'PAYMENTREQUEST_1_AMT'=>urlencode('100'),
     'PAYMENTREQUEST_1_ITEMAMT'=>urlencode('50'),
     'PAYMENTREQUEST_1_TAXAMT'=>urlencode('50'),
     'PAYMENTREQUEST_1_DESC'=>urlencode('Dancing class'),
     'PAYMENTREQUEST_1_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID'=>urlencode('himans_1320303266_biz@smartdatainc.net'),
     'PAYMENTREQUEST_1_PAYMENTACTION'=>urlencode('Order'),
     'PAYMENTREQUEST_1_PAYMENTREQUESTID'=>urlencode('CART26485-PAYMENT0')
  );

  $curl = curl_init('https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp');                       
        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER ,1);                              
        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPGET ,true);                                    
        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS ,$data);              
   $response = curl_exec($curl);
   echo $response;
   exit;
   curl_close($curl);         
?>
```

Here is the vardump of the request:

```
array(15) { 
  ["USER"]=> string(43) "XXX"
  ["PWD"]=> string(10) "XXX"
  ["SIGNATURE"]=> string(56) "XXX"
  ["VERSION"]=> string(4) "56.0"
  ["METHOD"]=> string(18) "SetExpressCheckout"
  ["RETURNURL"]=> string(78)
    "http%3A%2F%2F75.125.190.162%3A7132%2Fsample%2Fphp_nvp_samples%2FmyCheckout.php"
  ["CANCELURL"]=> string(78)
    "http%3A%2F%2F75.125.190.162%3A7132%2Fsample%2Fphp_nvp_samples%2FmyCheckout.php"
  ["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE"]=> string(3) "USD"
  ["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT"]=> string(3) "100"
  ["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT"]=> string(2) "50"
  ["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT"]=> string(2) "20"
  ["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC"]=> string(13) "Dancing class"
  ["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID"]=> string(21) "seller-136@paypal.com"
  ["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION"]=> string(5) "Order"
  ["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTREQUESTID"]=> string(18) "CART26485-PAYMENT0"
}
```

*API Credentials removed intentionally.*

And here is the response:

```
   TIMESTAMP=2012%2d03%2d06T09%3a29%3a41Z
  &CORRELATIONID=184b37b1fd85
  &ACK=Failure
  &L_ERRORCODE0=10001
  &L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Internal%20Error
  &L_LONGMESSAGE0=Timeout%20processing%20request
```

Comment: Please add a var_dump of $data; that should help in finding out what's wrong.

Comment: Try to increase your version. If you're not using a test credit card number, and getting 10001, then it's something very minute. Something the PayPal engineers didn't map error codes for because it would be a waste of time. I will try to look through the data you are sending to see if I can come up with something..

Comment: @techie_28 I cleaned up the code, and in the process I saw that you left your PayPal API credentials after the response section - check an earlier revision of your question. If these credentials are for your live account, you should ensure that you have changed your credentials since.

Answer (score 2):

I apologize for my oversight with my other answer. Please look at your code, and you will see that you only have one payment request, 0, but two sellers. You have to increase the 'n' in PAYMENTREQUEST_n_ to send multiple payments using parallel payments.

However, I must admit that whenever I send the same exact data as you, I get a 10400 "order total is missing", so I would look further into your code.

I get a successful response with the following:

**API Request:**

```
 USER=*************************** 
 PWD=***************************
 SIGNATURE=***************************
 METHOD=SetExpressCheckout 
 VERSION=86.0 
 RETURNURL=http://www.site.com/checkout.php 
 CANCELURL=http://www.site.com/cancel.php 
 PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale 
 PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=524.20 
 PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=458.00 
 PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT=20.00 
 PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT=46.20 
 PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD 
 PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC=test EC payment 
 PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTREQUESTID=111 
 L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=Books 
 L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=154.00 
 L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0=ABC123 
 L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=2 
 L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME1=CDs 
 L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT1=50.00 
 L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER1=BY-Z4736 
 L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY1=3 
 PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID=seller1@paypal.com 
 PAYMENTREQUEST_1_PAYMENTACTION=Sale 
 PAYMENTREQUEST_1_AMT=494.20 
 PAYMENTREQUEST_1_ITEMAMT=428.00 
 PAYMENTREQUEST_1_SHIPPINGAMT=20.00 
 PAYMENTREQUEST_1_TAXAMT=46.20 
 PAYMENTREQUEST_1_CURRENCYCODE=USD 
 PAYMENTREQUEST_1_DESC=test EC payment 
 PAYMENTREQUEST_1_PAYMENTREQUESTID=222 
 L_PAYMENTREQUEST_1_NAME0=DVDs 
 L_PAYMENTREQUEST_1_AMT0=154.00 
 L_PAYMENTREQUEST_1_NUMBER0=ABC123 
 L_PAYMENTREQUEST_1_QTY0=2 
 L_PAYMENTREQUEST_1_NAME1=Computers 
 L_PAYMENTREQUEST_1_AMT1=40.00 
 L_PAYMENTREQUEST_1_NUMBER1=BY-Z4736 
 L_PAYMENTREQUEST_1_QTY1=3 
 PAYMENTREQUEST_1_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID=seller2@paypal.com
```

**API Response:**

```
TOKEN=EC-4XP542213W924160A
TIMESTAMP=2012-03-07T05:16:27Z
CORRELATIONID=357d629ee6eda
ACK=Success
VERSION=86.0
BUILD=2571254
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a Payflow test credit card?

Payflow's test credit cards are banned in the sandbox, in a word. You will always get a 10001 response with the below [Payflow test credit cards (see page 49 & 50)](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/CA/en_US/files/developer/PP_PayflowPro_Guide.pdf):

- American Express

  - 378282246310005
  - 371449635398431
- American Express Corporate

  - 378734493671000
- Diners Club

  - 30569309025904
  - 38520000023237
- Discover

  - 6011111111111117
  - 6011000990139424
- JCB

  - 3530111333300000
  - 3566002020360505
- MasterCard

  - 5555555555554444
  - 5105105105105100
- Visa

  - 4111111111111111
  - 4012888888881881
  - 4222222222222
    -- NOTE: Even though this number has a different character count than the 
    other test numbers, it is the correct and functional number

Comment: Thanx for your attention I am not using any credit card number

Answer (score 0):

If you're still seeing an error, remove;

```
["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTREQUESTID"]=> string(18) "CART26485-PAYMENT0"
```